# Failed to load resource on Skype WebChat

Tags: javascript, api, web-services, skype

I am trying to use the WebChat Skype with the code listed on this page [Skype - Web Control](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol), the example is very simple with a div on `<html>` and one script of JS, but the console show some errors with `code 403 to call "edge.skype.com"` and others elements.

I only copy and paste the code list of [Skype - Web Control](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol) and put the secret_key of channel skype from platform botframework and actually I use certificate SSL on my webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Send welcome event</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-bot-id="MY-BOT-ID"></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js">
      SkypeWebControl.SDK.start();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

//THIS IS THE ERROR ON CONSOLE

```
setup complete
[Report Only] Refused to load the font 'https://swc.cdn.skype.com/assets/fonts/SkypeAssets-Light.woff' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

edge.skype.com/pcs-df/contacts/v2/users/guest%3A75b1fb07-f6da-46a0-8ab7-26cf5899e8d9?page_size=100&reason=default:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

28:05711932-9d03-42d0-b3ca-433e99588844:1 GET https://client-s.gateway.messenger.live.com/v1/users/ME/conversations/28:05711932-9d03-42d0-b3ca-433e99588844?view=msnp24Equivalent&targetType=All 404 (Not Found)

poll:1 POST https://client-s.gateway.messenger.live.com/v1/users/ME/endpoints/SELF/subscriptions/0/poll 404 (Not Found)
```

I hope can use the bubble chat of skype without error and can show one message of welcome to the user when he  open chat.